# Как посчитать количество обращений к Yandex JavaScript API для определения лимита при покупке платной версии?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, лицензирование

Имеется запрос на отображение карты с маршрутом и промежуточными точками:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(init);

    function init() {
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: ${lonlatCenter} ,
            zoom: 13
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });
**Далее, в цикле, добавляются объекты**
 <s:iterator value="routeResultList">
        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([<s:property value="y_position" />, <s:property value="x_position" />], {
            hintContent: '<s:property value="address" />',
            balloonContent:  '<s:property value="person" /><br><s:property value="check_result" escapeHtml="false"/>'
        }, {
            iconLayout: 'default#image',
            <s:if test="%{state == 1}">
            iconImageHref: 'images/Q_8.png',
            </s:if>
            <s:elseif test="%{state == 2}">
            iconImageHref: 'images/Q_4.png',
            </s:elseif>
            <s:elseif test="%{state == 3}">
            iconImageHref: 'images/Q_6.png',
            </s:elseif>
            <s:else>
            iconImageHref: 'images/cross.png',
            </s:else>
            iconImageSize: [30, 42],
            iconImageOffset: [-3, -42],
        });
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
        </s:iterator>
**После этого - маршруты:**
myMap.geoObjects.add(
                new ymaps.Polyline([
                            <s:iterator value="trackArray">
                            [<s:property value="y" />,<s:property value="x" />],
                        </s:iterator>
                        ], {}, {
                    strokeColor: "#C9302C",
                    // Ширина линии.
                    strokeWidth: 3
                })
        );
}
</script>
```

Вопрос заключается в том, как будет считать яндекс количество обращений к АПИ, по количеству отображений собранного объекта (карты с маршрутами) или по количеству объектов на карте, добавленных в ходе сборки?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде нет маршрутов. Вы добавляете на карту метки и линии. Они добавляются координатами, а не адресами - геокодер не задействуется и расхода лимитных запросов нет совсем.

Посмотрите ещё раз [список тарифицируемых запросов](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index.html#index__limits). Если кратко - это геокодирование (адрес в координаты и наоборот), построение маршрутов (не рисование объектов) и панорамы.

Если ваш сценарий использования не удовлетворяет [условиям бесплатного использования](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/), и необходимо приобретать коммерческую лицензию, достаточно будет купить минимальный [тариф](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/commercial/doc/concepts/jsapi-geocoder.html#jsapi-geocoder__standart) сервиса.